# Do I need to use defined?

Tags: perl

Is there any difference between these 2:

```
print "Undefined\n" unless defined $test;
```

and

```
print "Undefined\n" unless $test;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number 0, the string '0' and the empty string ('') are all defined, but false. If you run your code with `$test` set to any of those three values, you will see the difference.

The `defined` test checks whether a value is defined. A `defined` variable has been given a value. Any value. Even one that is false.

(Ok, not the value `undef`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
print "Undefined\n" unless defined $test;
```

print Undefined if `$test` is `undef`;

```
print "Undefined\n" unless $test;
```

print Undefined if `$test` is `undef` or `$test == 0` or `$test eq ''`

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining the difference between _definedness_ and _truth_ in Perl.

Comment: Note also that, while the string "0" is false, the string "00" is true (and both are `== 0`).

Comment: Last line more better written as: *print Undefined if `$test eq '0'` (including the number zero 0) or `$test eq ''` (including `undef`).*